# Select multiple top 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have this table with data:

```
   ID   |   Data   
--------+---------
    1   |   ONE
    2   |   ONE
    3   |   ONE
    5   |   TWO
    7   |   TWO
    10  |   TWO
    15  |   THREE
    14  |   THREE
    8   |   THREE
```

and I want to get this result

```
   ID   |   Data   
--------+---------
    1   |   ONE
    5   |   TWO
    15  |   THREE
```

so I want to collect only first record of each value in Data. Values ONE, TWO, THREE may exist in second table so I can get them merged using join. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Try this -

```
Select Min(ID), Data
From YourTableAfterAllJoinsYouWant
Group By Data
```

You won't need to join if your `Data` table already has column `Data` in it. Or else, you can replace the `YourTableAfterAllJoinsYouWant` with joined tables.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that the order may vary so min() will not always give correct results

Comment: @BlaBla you need you specify how to get the "correct" row then.  You gave only 2 fields and the "correct" answer in your sample was always the `MIN()`

Comment: In that case you can always do the `order by` on the primary key of the table. In case you have none, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate a unique numbers for each row. If you do not have any ordering scheme, then _per_my_understanding_ SQL can give results in any order without being _incorrect_.

Comment: @JNK, I want to get top(1) records in chronological order, but I don't have date column in database. I think that min(ID) is great but what if IDs are generated randomly(for some purpose) and I want to get the first of each kind?

Comment: Then you need to add a date column.  **There is no guaranteed innate sort order in SQL.**